# Hiding a div through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My question is I have a div and I want to make it invisible through a javascript function, easy as that, seems like something a lot of people would have done, and I've researched it pretty thoroughly, however it doesn't seem to work. Here is my code (greatly simplified to just show the problem) Forgive the poor HTML formatting, I did that to keep the website from thinking I was trying to post a link.

```
function HideDiv()  
{   
   var elem = Document.getElementById('divID');  
   elem.style.display = "none";  
   elem.style.visibility = "hidden";  
}

function buttonFunction()  
{

   var elem = Document.getElementById('buttonID'); 
   elem.src="a new url";

}

<div id="divID" style="background: url('a url') top center no-repeat " >
<center>
   <anchor onclick="buttonFunction" (a hyper reference here)="#">
   <img src="a url" vspace ="35" border = "0" id="buttonID">
   </anchor>
</center>
</div>
```

Does having those anchors in the div prevent the hiding functionality? The reason I have both display and visibility on the div is that my understanding is that those functions work differently between firefox and IE, so I included both as a way to make sure that regardless of browser this will work. I have tried using either function individually in FF IE and Chrome to no result, the Div remains visible. Additionally, I'd like the anchors to become invisible as well if at all possible.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: I hope the <center> tag is part of the "Forgive the poor HTML" part...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Document` should be `document`.

I'm also not sure if having `<anchor>` instead of `<a>` was part of your attempt to "keep the website from thinking I was trying to post a link". (See David's answer below for how the entire `<a>` should be written.)

It may not be shown here, but I can't see where `HideDiv()` is called from.

Comment: Box is right. 'Document' is likely the Class - 'document' is an instance of that class on the page, technically it's a property of 'window', so - window.document.getElementByID() is basically the same thing.

Comment: Wow, that was what I did wrong, talk about a dumb mistake, fast answers too, I am humbled. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a onclick="buttonFunction(); return false;" href="#">
   <img src="url" vspace ="35" border = "0" id="buttonID" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery makes this easy.

$("#divId").hide();

(haven't tried this, but I'm sure it's close to the correct syntax)

Comment: `elem.style.display = "none";` is easy too.